# Program for downloading MMS/RTMP files

Tags: multimedia, media-manager, rtmp, mms

For [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol), I already tried [RTMPDump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTMPDump). It's very difficult and complicated to use in the terminal. Is there a GUI-based alternative?

For MMS, I already tried Firefox's plugin, and some download manager. It downloads only a junk file or stream file, not full at all.

And saving with [VLC media player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player), it's working, but it takes a very long time to do (I think VLC media player is converting the file format after the download. Can I save without converting?)

Comment: I've done this with VLC in the past with 0 issues. I'll try to remember to try this myself when I get home.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could try streamripper, which is in the repositories. It is a command line application though.

Answer (score 1):

Try [mtvidownload](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mtvidownload) for downloading files over RTMPE. There is a YouTube video on how to use this, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmWN50iX_9Q.